# error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPokemon'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Running this code :

```
 <app-pokemon-form *ngIf="showPokemonForm" (newPokemonEvent)="addNewPokemon($event)" 
    (pokemonFormClose)="pokemonFormClose($event)"
      [pokemon]="currentPokemon"></app-pokemon-form>
```

Causes an error :

**error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IPokemon'.**

Here is the TypeScript File:

```
 addNewPokemon(newPokemon: IPokemon): void {
    console.log('adding new pokemon ' + JSON.stringify(newPokemon));
    this.pokemonService.addPokemon({ ...newPokemon })
      .subscribe({
        next: pokemon => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(pokemon) + ' has been added');
          this.message = "new pokemon has been added";
        },
        error: (err) => this.message = err
      });
```

And here is the pokemon model itself:

```
export interface IPokemon {
    _id: string,
    Name: string,
    Generation: Number,
    Type: string
}
```

Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated

Comment: You're passing in $event into the addNewPokemon function. Judging by the error message, $event is of type Event and can't be used.

Comment: You might not be receiving what you think you are getting when `addNewPokemon` gets invoked. You might want to temporarily change the signature to addNewPokemon(newPokemon: any) and see 1) if you are still getting the typing error and 2) if you are getting what you expected in your console.log statement

Answer (score 0):

Since your argument `$event` is of type `Event`, meaning it does not (necessarily) have the form of

```
interface IPokemon {
  _id: string,
  Name: string,
  Generation: number,
  Type: string
}
```

you cannot pass `$event` to your `addPokemon` method.

You can check the form of the `$event` parameter if it matches with the `IPokemon` interface and if

- **not**: make sure that `$event` has the appropriate form, or
- **if yes:** you can add `$event as unknown as IPokemon` in your function call